# Jquery Data Table 1.9.0 not working with POST method

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable version 1.9.0 with Asp.net but when i change  'sServerMethod' as 'POST' rather than sending POST request its sending GET request and because of that Sensitive information is being visible. I am doing this because i don`t want to send Sensitive information using Get Request as it can be track. You can check below code and let me know where i am doing mistake.

> ```
>         var csrfField = $("#__CSRFTOKEN").val();
>         var oTable = $('.reportTable.rmaqueue').dataTable({
>             'bSortable': true,
>             "bDestroy": true,
>             'iDisplayLength': 10,
>             'iDisplayStart': 0,
>             'bProcessing': true,
>             'bServerSide': true,
>             "bFilter": false,
>             'sPaginationType': "full_numbers",
>             "bStateSave": false,
>             "bSort": true,
>             'sServerMethod': 'POST',
>             'fnServerParams': function (aoData) {
>                 aoData.push({ "name": "__CSRFTOKEN", "value": csrfField });
>             },
>             "aoColumns": [
>                             null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
>                             {
>                                 "bSearchable": false,
>                                 "bSortable": false,
>                                 "fnRender": function (oObj) {
>                                     return "<a title='Edit' href='AssetEdit.aspx?assetid=" + oObj.aData[9] + " ' class='btnStandard'>Edit</a>";
>                                 }
>                             },
>                             {
>                                 "bVisible": false
>                             }
>             ],
>             'sAjaxSource': urlHandler,
> });
> ```

Can anyone help me why its not working with 1.9.0 version.

Comment: All requests can be tracked. Not only GET requests. If you use a program like Fiddler you will see that all requests and responses can be stored

Comment: I guess you are using this script -> **https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html** (or one of the other legacy serverside scripts) - change all `$_GET` to `$_POST` in that file.